# Can I add a String as a parameter to a traditional for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, initialization

I realize this isn't a huge issue, but I'd like to accomplish something like this for code cleanliness within my tests.  (I also realize "clean" is subjective, and I'd rather not get into a code review session, haha.)  For some reason, the traditional `for` loop refuses to allow a `String` as one of the variables that's initialized within it.  Currently, what I have that compiles is the following:

```
Iterator<String> keys = map.keySet().iterator();
String next = null;
for(int i = 0; keys.hasNext(); i++, next = keys.next()) {
    //stuff
}
```

... but it would be nice to have something like this:

```
for(int i = 0, String next = null; keys.hasNext(); i++, next = keys.next()) {
    //stuff
}
```

The reason I would expect this to work is because we can have `for` loops like such with multiple variables.

```
for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < 0 && j < 0; i++, j++) {
    // stuff
}
```

Unfortunately, the `String` version gives compiler errors, for whatever reason.  Is there a way I can accomplish this? Do I just have some syntax error?  If it *is* impossible, is there a reason why?

---

For everyone who's frustrated and wants to argue that this is stupid, the reason I need `i` as well as the `Iterator` is for JUnit testing purposes.  I have a `LinkedHashMap` (which is ordered) and I need to assert that the first element = X, the second element = Y, the third element = Z, and so forth.  But the `keySet()` returns only a `Set` which doesn't allow you to fetch by index.  You can only iterate over it.  Therefore I need the `i` variable to keep track of where I'm at in the iterator for the assertions.

Comment: Note that if your example *did* work, `next` would be `null` on the first pass through the loop, which I'm guessing isn't what you want.

Comment: I was throwing it together for example purposes to produce the compiler error, not for practical functionality. :)

Comment: if you never use the variable i, why not use a while(keys.hasNext())?

Comment: I suggest you to get rid of this loop and use the for-each statement: 
`int i = 0;
        for(String s : map.keySet()) {
            //do stuff
            i++;
        }`

Comment: @spyr03 It's for testing.  The `Set` is in fact ordered, and I want to check particular indexes.  Unfortunately, the ordering isn't preserved by nature in the `keySet`.  (Can't fetch by index, must use iterator.)

Comment: @user2336315 There's no point in manually incrementing `i++` within another loop.

Comment: @asteri I don't see another loop. I see one loop which iterates over the keys returned by the iterator and one variable `i` that is incremented before the next iteration (as you said you need the "index").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The initialization part of the [`for` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1) only accepts that you declare variables of one type. 
So you can have multiple declarations, but they must all be of the same type and that type can be `String`.

```
for (String example = "some string"; example.length() > 0; example = example.substring(1))
    System.out.println(example);
```

or with a list of declarations

```
for (String example = "some string", another = "woot", someMore = "these too!"; example.length() > 0; example = example.substring(1))
    System.out.println(example);
```

Comment: Interesting.  Just tested it, though, and it still doesn't allow multiple `String` objects, even if they are the only type.

Comment: Maybe that's a separate question, though.

Comment: @asteri Please clarify. I've added an example.

Comment: Simply add another `String` in the initialization portion.  `  for (String example = "some string", String another = ""; example.length() > 0; example = example.substring(1))`

Comment: @asteri I suspect you specified the type for the second String. For example `for (String example = "some string", String test = "hello";...; ...)` does not compile, but `for (String example = "some string", test = "hello"; ...; ...);` does

Comment: @asteri Yeah, just like you did with your `i` and `j` sample.

Comment: Nevermind, I'm stupid.  All you have to do is take out the second type and it's fine, e.g., `for(String example = null, another = null...`

Comment: I don't suppose anyone knows a reason *why* they must all be the same type?  Or is it just because of the syntax?

Comment: @asteri Most probably. Declaration statements (with or without initialization expressions) are separated with semi colons. If we added semi colons here, we'd be messing with the semi colon as separate for the `for` loop parts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this? It saves the keylist to an arraylist an iterates over that

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("A", "AA");
map.put("B", "BB");

List<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>(map.keySet());
for(String s:keys) {
    System.out.println(keys.indexOf(s)+" "+s);
    // stuff
}
```

EDIT: I know you are looking for cleaner code, but making the for loop longer isn't necessarily to way to go, variable names and proper formatting would make code much cleaner than changing how you iterate over a map imo

Comment: Right, I know how I can accomplish what I'm trying to do.  It's not a matter of being unable, it's a matter of why I can't do it in a particular way.

Comment: what exactly are you iterating over?

Comment: A Map's key set.  And per your edit, that's exactly why I said in the question that I didn't want to get into subjective code review, haha.

Comment: Ok, I think I had a way of going over a map without an iterator before, I understand now

Comment: Your idea of converting to an `ArrayList` is really good.  It doesn't answer the question (which is about general syntax and code possibility), but it's a good idea.